# What is this unusual CREATE TABLE syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create DB.
I have a script file .sql like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [AlleleFreqBySsPop]
(
[subsnp_id] [int] NOT NULL ,
[pop_id] [int] NOT NULL ,
[allele_id] [int] NOT NULL ,
[source] [varchar](2) NOT NULL ,
[cnt] [real] NULL ,
[freq] [real] NULL ,
[last_updated_time] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

It seems to be different from mysql or postgresql.

What type of languige is this? How can I use it?

Comment: Does it run in MySQL? It's still SQL, but it's using square brackets as name delimiters. Not sure what db platforms support that, but try it in the db you're expecting it to work in... `:)`

Comment: `[` and `]` are common delimiters on MSSQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the square brackets and the `GO` keyword, I would say that this is [T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189826.aspx) (MS SQL Server). To use it in MySQL, you could probably just remove the square brackets and solve incompatibilities (ie. types or missing escaping) from there on.

I just tested this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6064), and simply removing the square brackets is enough in this case. For other DDL statements however, you may have to substitute types (ie. `datetime2` from T-SQL is not supported in MySQL), and you may run into other problems - like the need to escape column names that are reserved keywords in one dialect but not the other, etc. The usual SQL databases [do not use 100% standards compliant SQL](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/).

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you are referring to the `[text]`, focusing on the brackets? This is just a delimiter for names.

[Here is a SQLFiddle to show this working in MS SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e212b)

[Here is a SQLFiddle to show this working in SqlLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e1159) (but only if you have removed the `GO` at the end(Thanks to Ypercube for pointing that out)...otherwise, it is just MSSQL that will work)

It does appear to error in the MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle. Hopefully, that helps clear things up. SqlFiddle is a great tool to check things like this :)

[Here is the SQL Server documentation on delimited identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:mysql].

Comment: @eggyal I have clarified my answer further for each language

Comment: Valid point by Justin. Still, the `GO` means that it won't work in SQLite. Only in SQL-Server.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89538 will make it work in mysql, just remove the brackets and replace go with the semicolon

Comment: @ypercube Ahh, I had stripped that out and will note in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Its SQL thats using `[` and `]` as delimiters or "Non Quoted Identifier" so, probably from a TSQL source.

I believe if you subsitute `[` and `]` for valid delimiters on your platform or setup, or just remove them, then it should be perfectly valid SQL.

In general delimiters are a good thing and can help the SQL engine to parse the query.